# How can I get the names associated with the user guids in Rstudio connect api?

Tags: r, rstudio-connect, rstudioapi

How can I get the names associated with the user guids

```
> ## ACTION REQUIRED: Change the server URL below to your server's URL
> Sys.setenv("CONNECT_SERVER"  = "https://rstudio.xx.com/") 
> ## ACTION REQUIRED: Make sure to have your API key ready
> Sys.setenv("CONNECT_API_KEY" = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Enter Connect Token:")) 

> library(ggplot2)
> library(dplyr)
> library(connectapi)
> library(purrr)
> client <- connect()
Defining Connect with server: https://rstudio.hartvillegroup.com/
> # Get and clean the Shiny usage data
> shiny_rsc <- get_usage_shiny(
+   client,
+   from = lubridate::today() - lubridate::ddays(60), 
+   limit = Inf
+ ) %>%
+   filter(!is.na(ended)) %>%
+   mutate(session_duration = ended - started)
> 
> glimpse(shiny_rsc)
Observations: 129
Variables: 6
$ content_guid     <chr> "a261edd3-fa51-4878-8afc-b7fe662a6c37", "a261edd3-fa51-4878...
$ user_guid        <chr> "e96068bd-5e9f-4a5a-ab87-483f084f13fa", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
$ started          <dttm> 2021-07-06 14:39:24, 2021-07-06 15:08:47, 2021-07-06 21:40...
$ ended            <dttm> 2021-07-06 14:49:17, 2021-07-06 16:15:44, 2021-07-06 22:20...
$ data_version     <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
$ session_duration <drtn> 593 secs, 4017 secs, 2424 secs, 4329 secs, 2642 secs, 3286.
```

As you see the user_guid are identifiers. how do I link them with actual user names? or is that always encrypted.

Comment: Have you tried the [get_users()](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/connectapi/reference/get_users.html) function to get a list of users? That will likely tell you who belongs to each GUID.

Answer (score 1):

It's not giving you and encrypted username, it's the GUID/UUID key from the user info table in RStudio's instrumentation API.

Using `connectapi`:

```r
library(connectapi)
client <- connect("https://...", api_key = apikey)
get_users(client)
```

where the last field is `"guid"` which should match the `user_guid` in your question. Note that you may need to extend `limit=...` to get all users. The output is the same as the `httr`-direct API call, below.

---

If you (or somebody) is choosing to not use the `connectapi` package (it's not on CRAN yet, for instance), then the below function along with the `httr` package (and `data.table` for my personal use, but that dependency can be removed) will get you exactly the same data. (For reference, see https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/api/#get-/v1/users .)

```r
library(data.table)
getpages <- function(url, page_number = 1, page_size = 25, page_limit = Inf, apikey = "") {
  needqm <- !grepl("\\?", url)
  firstpass <- TRUE
  results <- list()
  res0 <- NULL
  while (page_number <= page_limit &&
           (firstpass || (length(res0) > 0 && nrow(res0) > 0))) {
    firstpass <- FALSE
    url0 <- sprintf("%s%spage_number=%d&page_size=%d",
                    url, if (needqm) "?" else "&", page_number, page_size)
    res <- httr::GET(url0, httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste("Key", apikey)))
    if (isTRUE(res$status_code == 200L)) {
      res0 <- suppressWarnings(rbindlist(httr::content(res)$results, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
      results <- c(results, list(res0))
    } else {
      warning("returned status_code of: ", res$status_code)
      break
    }
    page_number <- page_number + 1L
  }
  out <- rbindlist(results, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  out[]
}

userinfo <- getpages("https://rsc.mydomain.com/__api__/v1/users", apikey = "....")
head(userinfo)
#                  email username first_name last_name user_role         created_time         updated_time               active_time confirmed locked                                 guid
#                 <char>   <char>     <char>    <char>    <char>               <char>               <char>                    <char>    <lgcl> <lgcl>                               <char>
# 1: user1@somewhere.com    user1     first1     last1    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE 33fdbc12-167f-42e6-b119-816fb46e7de1
# 2: user2@somewhere.com    user2     first2     last2    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE becd98ce-472e-4c62-a7c7-63f856ea72d3
# 3: user3@somewhere.com    user3     first3     last3    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE 9cc751bb-351d-4613-9b39-af35547a971b
# 4: user4@somewhere.com    user4     first4     last4    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE 10276566-6922-4c4b-83b1-30dbe4b8f136
# 5: user5@somewhere.com    user5     first5     last5    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE 81c2b393-b862-4615-bbcd-3c2e1d2c990b
# 6: user6@somewhere.com    user6     first6     last6    viewer 2019-04-12T23:08:39Z 2019-06-11T09:28:41Z 2019-06-15T08:05:17-04:00      TRUE  FALSE 7803fa60-9906-49f3-a26b-157d15a33ddb
```

Comment: I don't know, tbh. When I reached out to RStudio for commercial support a few months ago, they recommended direct API usage instead of that package. I don't know their rationale, perhaps because it is not on CRAN?

Comment: (And since `remotes::install_github('rstudio/connectapi')` is *currently* returning 404, oddly enough, I'm not able to do anything further.)

Comment: I agree ... but now I'm flummoxed by the 404 error ... it seems to be specific to that repo, since I just installed another github-based package.

Comment: ahhhh ... `ref="main"`, they've made the switch

Comment: *Obviously* something older than that ;-). Yes, lots of packages could probably use an update. Doing that blindly in the middle of reporting season can lead to exciting times.